# What kind of javascript conditional statements are these?

Tags: javascript

In some code I inherited at work, I'm trying to figure out how these conditions work here, but I'm unsure of how it's structured and what type of conditional statements these are (this originated the jQuery jBox plugin)

```
this._fireEvent = function( event, pass ) {
   // This condition here
   this.options[ event ] && ( this.options[ event ].bind( this ) )( pass );
};
```

And this second condition:

```
this.options.pointTo == 'target' && (!this.options.outside || this.options.outside == 'xy') && (this.options.pointer = false);
```

The first one I can tell, in a traditional if statement, would be...

```
if ( this.options[ event ] ) {
   this.options[event].bind( this )( pass );
}
```

Is there a name or methodology for these types of conditional statements? And how would you read that second one in terms of what it's doing?

Would really appreciate any help or insight that someone could provide!

Comment: They’re just conditionals—I’m not sure what you’re asking.

Comment: Noting that the `this.options.pointer = false` seems sketchy at best.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
this.options[ event ] && ( this.options[ event ].bind( this ) )( pass );
```

if equivilent to

```
if (this.options[ event ] ) 
    ( this.options[ event ].bind( this ) )( pass );
```

or

```
this.options[ event ] ? ( this.options[ event ].bind( this ) )( pass ) : null
```

this

```
this.options.pointTo == 'target' && (!this.options.outside || this.options.outside == 'xy') && (this.options.pointer = false);
```

is almost the same as

```
this.options.pointTo == 'target' ? (!this.options.outside : this.options.outside == 'xy') && (this.options.pointer = false);
```

or the equivalent if statement of course

so to sum up:

`&&` will execute the right side if and only if the left side  is true

`||` will execute the right side if and only if the left side if false

Answer (score 2):

They are just compound statements that include the short-circuited logical AND (`&&`) and the short-circuited logical OR (`||`) operators to test for multiple things at once.

- Short-circuited AND means that if any condition fails (processing
  from left to right), the entire expression fails and do not continue
  to evaluate the expression.
- Short-circuited OR means that if any condition succeeds
  (processing from left to right), the entire expression succeeds and
  do not continue to evaluate the expression.

Additionally, the grouping operator `()` is used to group conditions together, effectively creating conditions that must be evaluated independently of the rest of the expression.

Answer (score 1):

Its called short circuit statement evaluation. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators

And you read it based on the order of precedence: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Operator_Precedence

So in your case it will be read as:
`'target' && (!this.options.outside || this.options.outside == 'xy') && (this.options.pointer = false);`

`First_truthy_value && (Second block evaluation) && (Third block evaluation which finally gets returned as a 'value')`

Your third block however is an assignment statement `this.options.pointer = false` which will always return `false`